# obtaining bounds with Google Geolocation, is this correct?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Geolocation with great success. Yesterday, we made a move to improve our storelocator script by searching from the bounds of the users location. Therefore, when we geolocate, we also need the users northeast and southwest latitude and longitude bounds.

We are obtaining these from the console as follows (I'm pasting the entire geolocating function, in case this helps):

```
$('#geomate').click(function() { 
var geocoder;
var split1;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng);
}
function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geolocator failed. If you're on a mobile device, please switch on your Location settings (GPS)");
}
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results)
            if (results[1]) {
                split1 = results[1].formatted_address.split(', ');
                swlat = results[1].geometry.bounds.Ca.k;
                swlng = results[1].geometry.bounds.va.j;
                nelat = results[1].geometry.bounds.Ca.j;
                nelng = results[1].geometry.bounds.va.k;
                //formatted address

                //if zipcode has a value, clear it first
                if ($('input[name="zipcode"]').val() != '') {
                $('input[name="zipcode"]').val('');
                }
                //now enter the geolocation
                $('input[name="zipcode"]').val(split1[1] + ', ' + split1[2]);
                // if hidden geomtery fields exist, remove them
                $('.storelocator_body form').find('.geomerty').remove();
                $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomerty" name="lat" value="' + lat + '">');
                $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomerty" name="lng" value="' + lng + '">');
                $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomerty" name="swlat" value="' + swlat + '">');
                $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomerty" name="swlng" value="' + swlng + '">');
                $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomerty" name="nelat" value="' + nelat + '">');
                $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomerty" name="nelng" value="' + nelng + '">');
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

What I wonder is, is there a simpler way to get the bounds from the geolocation request? For example, I have tried to obtain the bounds via the following code:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swLatLn, neLatLn);
```

however I was unsuccessful, because the console returns the error " Uncaught ReferenceError: swLatLn is not defined".

Many thanks!

Comment: Down vote obviously from a person having a bad morning ;-) I've done a lot of research to be able to geocode & reverse geocode. In fact most of the above code comes from an answer that had quite a few up votes here on SA. So to down vote my question makes no sense. It can be VERY helpful to some other amateur (!) who may also want to get the bounds of a location. Especially as I haven't seen a similar question here on SA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `results[1].geometry.bounds.Ca.k;` and such. These are undocumented properties that are subject to change.

Instead use the [documented LatLngBounds methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()` which return a `LatLng`.

If you need the latitude and longitude values you can get them with the `lat()` and `lng()` methods:

```
var lat = results[1].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
var lng = results[1].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
// And so on...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this certainly did help. thank you for that. Every day I'm learning a little more.